# Not able to hit the URL of webservices from postman

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have created a web service and deployed on a working server. but whenever I am trying to hit the server from the postman. I am getting the following error in the log file.

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'MyMobileWebService': initialization started
2018-11-21 05:02:43,414 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MyMobileWebService-servlet.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter#45c237ec' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter] for bean with name 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter#45c237ec' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MyMobileWebService-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter] for bean with name 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter#45c237ec' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MyMobileWebService-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
```

I am stuck in this but not able to find the correct solution

**MyMobile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Component scan to find all Spring components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.MyMobile" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <!-- Default converters -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="MyMobileActivityControllerProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>
                    classpath:/config/MyMobile/MyMobile.activityController.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="MyMobileActionControllerProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>
                    classpath:/config/MyMobile/MyMobile.actionController.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

can anyone please give me some suggestions where I am doing a mistake.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in xml file instead of `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌r`.

Notice the change Jackson2 instead of Jackson.

Because the first major version of Jackson is no longer supported in Spring 4.

Make sure that you have com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.x.x on your classpath.